# Excel 2010 VBA adodb connection to SQL Server 2010 login timeout

Tags: sql-server, vba, timeout, adodb

I spent several hours on this error and I can't find any relevant solution in my brain or on the internet.

I have written a few VBA macros in Excel 2010 that connect to a SQL Server 2008 database on my computer and get some information back. I used them for a few weeks and they worked fine.

2 days ago I set up SQL Server 2008 and Excel 2010 on a new computer, and tried to import my database and my VBA macros.

Here is the issue: When trying to use the macros, excel stop answering then crashed with a catastrophic failure when I forced the close. So I created a new empty database (called PR_db), created a new excel file, and tried to make just a simple connexion to the database with the following code:

```
Public Const cString = "Provider=SQLOLEDB; Data Source=tosh-TOSH; Initial Catalog=PR_db;Trusted_Connection=yes"

Dim objMyConn As Object
Set objMyConn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
objMyConn.Open
objMyConn.Close
```

This code worked for weeks on my previous computer. But on the new computer it results in a "login timeout error" 9 times out of 10 (Once in a while it works, then when I try again it doesn't work, even though I didn't change anything!)

I'm really lost here... any idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend reading more about connection strings.
http://www.connectionstrings.com/

Comment: I tried another connection string:
    Driver={SQL Server Native Client 10.0};Server=myServerAddress;Database=myDataBase;
    Trusted_Connection=yes;
and it worked well. Now I wonder why I never had an issue with the previous connection string on my first computer...

Anyway, thanks for the answer.

Comment: The code you have provided will not work nor execute. The connection string does not matter in that case anyways

Comment: What do you mean it will not work nor execute ? On vba, it works. Well in vba it's inside a Sub_procedure of course, but it works on my first computer.

Comment: Then I think you start over and reconsider if your sql server is configured properly.

http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server-2008

Comment: I'm sorry but your comment is not really helping me. Why do you say the connection string does not matter ? My sql server is probably not configured the best way since I just set it up on my computer and didn't change any setting, but I don't see what I should change in the configuration, and why.

Comment: because you are using a trusted connection that means youre not providing a user id and password because sql authenticates your windows login. if you havent configured that on the sql server then how are you expecting to establish a connection?

Comment: Oh, yes I use a trusted connection. The SQL Server's default settings were the windows login. When I log into the database using SQL Server Management Studio, I don't provide a user id or password either, because I use windows authentication.

Comment: Now with the new connection string ("Driver={SQL Server Native Client 10.0};Server=(local);Database=PR_db; Trusted_Connection=yes;") it works everytime on both computers. With the previous connection string it worked every time on my old computer, and 1 in 10 times on the new computer. I was never able to figure out what was different in the few times it worked.

Comment: I think its down to your RDBMS version and the driver you are using. Im glad youve got it working

Comment: Its often subtle differences between version of the SQL Drivers between different installations of Windows and SPs and HotFixes and initial setup of SQLServer etc.